# Loop through an array with special condition

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do save me some code with if statements so I do a loop here.

How can I do the following without creating a new array? I want to keep relying on the first $arr

This is a simple example, my array is actually much bigger than that :) So please keep that in mind, I have to check on the items of firstname and then do something.

````
$arr = ['man_firstname', 'man_lastname', 'woman_firstname', 'woman_lastname'];

// just making sure the value from db is set 
// otherwise set it to an empty string
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    isset($db[$item]) ? $$item = $db[$item] : $$item = '';
}

// with that loop I have now $man_firstname, $man_lastname, $woman_firstname
// and $woman_lastname  are all set to their db values or are empty

// now I want to echo both first name 
// and last name of the man and woman but ONLY WHEN THEIR FIRST NAMES IS NOT EMPTY

foreach (?? as ??) {
    if (!empty(firstname)) {
        // echo both first name and last name
    }
}

// desired results: echo "john doe" only if firstname of the man is set, 
// the same with "jenna smith" if her first name is not set then do 
// nothing with her array item```
````

Comment: show us the 2 array input data which your are using in your code. Add the expected outcome also. this will help us to understand your problem and give you solution. for me it seems `array_merge()` or `array_combine()` along with `array_filter()` and  `array_chunk()` will do the job.

Comment: Does the man first name and last name combined according the `_` in the `$arr` items?

Comment: I feel your first loop is wrong. You are fetching only that data as per the length of keys required

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem you want something like that :

```
$arr = ['john', 'doe', 'john', '', 'jenna', 'smith', '', 'smith'];

if (count($arr) % 2) {
   throw new Exception('Missing person name / surname !');
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i+=2) {
   if ($arr[$i] && $arr[$i+1]) {
      echo "{$arr[$i]} {$arr[$i+1]}<br>";
   }
}
```

Btw, keep in mind that in your array should be even number of names + surnames - otherwise you will not know what is missing - name or surname and for what person it is missing. That's why I've added exception generation in that case.